# The table option of beamer doesn't work

Tags: beamer, color

I've been using the option xcolor=table of beamer until now, and suddenly it stopped working.

When I code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{red}{green}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1&2\\
3&4\\
5&6\\
7&8
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get the error "\rowcolors undefined".

On the other hand, if I code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{red}{green}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1&2\\
3&4\\
5&6\\
7&8
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

it works.

I wonder why doing it the first way no longer works.

Comment: update to version 3.66

Comment: Please see this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642116/14103