# Package option (for xcolor) is not being properly used in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, package-options

After a recent upgrade of my system (to Ubuntu 22.04), many of my previous files are failing to compile with undefined colors.

Please see the following self-contained examples for clarification.

---

The following works fine.

```
% 1
% Base colors (always available)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\LaTeX

{\color{blue}\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

**Conclusion:** The `xcolor` package is working fine for the base colors.

---

The following works fine as well.

```
% 2
% Colors via dvipsnames option
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\LaTeX

{\color{Blue}\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

**Conclusion:** The `xcolor` package is working fine for the colors via option.

---

The following is also good.

```
% 3
% Base colors (always available)

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \LaTeX
  
  {\color{blue}\LaTeX}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Conclusion:** `beamer` properly handles the base colors in the
`xcolor` package.

---

This is where the problem starts.

```
% 4
% Colors via dvipsnames option
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \LaTeX
  
  {\color{Blue}\LaTeX}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

We get the following error message.

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined
> color `Blue'.

**Conclusion:** `beamer` fails to handle the colors via option in
`xcolor` package.

---

The following is likely to generate an option clash, naturally.

```
% 5
% Colors via dvipsnames option
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \LaTeX
  
  {\color{Blue}\LaTeX}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

We get the following error message.

> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package
> xcolor.

---

Even the following does not work when we pass the option explicitly.

```
% 6
% Colors via dvipsnames option
\documentclass{beamer}

\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \LaTeX
  
  {\color{Blue}\LaTeX}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

We get the following error message.

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined
> color `Blue'.

---

**Final Conclusion:** Something is wrong with `beamer` making it to fail to
handle the `xcolor` package options.

Comment: show the log-file of the failing example 4

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, The complete log file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/113Q-Q-Wyzliu-lGf5Xwc60pJAOaT5c-S/view?usp=sharing). Would you mind putting only the relevant portion in the post? I risk putting in too much redundant texts.

Comment: This was a bug in beamer v3.65 which was fixed in beamer v3.66; see the [changelog](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) here; "fixed regression of class options not being passed to packages like xcolor (see #759)". Your log file shows you're still using 3.65. I'm using 3.66 and don't get that error. Not sure how easy it is to upgrade using the Debian packages, but try.

Comment: See also the [original bug report](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/759) which gives a workaround, in case you can't easily upgrade.

Comment: More generally, the `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}` macro must be used **before** `\documentclass{...}`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks. Updated the solution.

Comment: @ Masroor please remove the solution from the question and copy it to the answer box and then (after 24 hours when it is allowed by the system) accept your own answer. This will properly mark the question as answered in the various lists, it will improve search results snippets and prevent the question from being deleted automatically.

Comment: duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634508/the-table-option-of-beamer-doesnt-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `beamer` v3.65 which was fixed in `beamer` v3.66. Those who are forced to use this version (upgrades may be difficult when you install the complete system), you can use the following workaround.

Load `xcolor`  or use the macro `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}`  before `\documentclass{...}`.

Use *either* of the following before `\documentclass{...}` in your file,

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
```

The second one is more modular.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `upgrades may be difficult when you install the complete system`?

Comment: @daleif, The texlive systems come pre-packaged in Ubuntu. Unless one knows what one is doing, it may be difficult to install the new packages and point to the correct path.

Comment: That is formulated incorrectly. If you installed texlive via your Linux dist and have noticed that the provided beamer version is buggy. Then it the Linux package **is** already installed and will be automatically updated once the Linux dist opdates the Linux package that contains beamer. Problem here is that the Linux dists seldomly (if ever) update their texlive Linux packages. Even if they know there are bugs in them that has been fixed.

Comment: @daleif, Rightly put.