# latex beamer xcolor: undefine color Yellow3

Tags: beamer, color

I inherited this file and I am trying to make it working.

When I try to compile it I get this error:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Yellow3'.
See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
l.88 \begin{document}
```

After I press `H`I do not get any output. I looked up this [Package option (for xcolor) is not being properly used in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641909/package-option-for-xcolor-is-not-being-properly-used-in-beamer) and I tryed to implement the accepted answer but no luck. Here is the relevant part of my document:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
%\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]


%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}

%% Font Settings

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape, series=\bfseries}

\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  language=python,
  emptylines=1,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
  moredelim=**[is][\color{red}]{@}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\color{brown}]{?}{?},
}
%% Color Settings

\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=Yellow3} 
\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=Yellow3} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 
 
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 


%% Create a table

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}


%% Item and enumerate style 

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square]
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=Yellow3,fg=white}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\color{Yellow3} \Neutral]}
%\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=Yellow3}

\newcommand{\mybullet}{\item[\textbullet]}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\mypen}{\item[\color{Yellow3} \ding{46}]}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}


%% FRAME 0 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=Yellow3!40!Khaki1}



\begin{frame}[plain] % to remove the navigation bar



\title{Title}
%\subtitle{}
\ \\[10pt]
\author{Name}
\date{\scriptsize \vspace{-0.5cm}\today}

\titlepage


\(\<{0.5\textwidth}
\scriptsize Left \\[5pt]  
\>
\<{0.3\textwidth}
\scriptsize Right\\[5pt]  
\>\)



\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT 1

Based on the accepted answer (see link above) I tried to add this line `\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` before `\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}`but I get the exact same error

---

EDIT 2

When I run `latex --version` I get the following output:

```
❯ latex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

Comment: your example is incomplete and can not be tested.

Comment: When you say that implementing the answer to the related question was 'no luck', what exactly do you mean? What did you try, and what happened when you tried that? To be sure: one of the options in that answer that should work is to put `\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}` _before_ `\documentclass`, i.e., put the options setting as the very first line in your file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @dexteritas Please see the edit

Comment: With my up-to-date TeX Live 2022, your problem works without any error message. However, you should reduce the document preamble, e.g., removing double loading of packages.

Comment: @cabohah It would be good to know which packages are double loading. Unfortunately I still get the same error

Comment: I've not examined all packages, but you are loading `listings` twice, TikZ also loads `graphicx` … I would suggest to use the method of making a MWE (see link in the second comment here) to reduce the preamble to the needed parts. BTW: An up to date binary says nothing about the packages you are using. Maybe this is indeed a problem with the package versions with debian's TeX Live packages. I'm always using vanilla TeX Live and update it at least once a week.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, based on accepted the answer to this question: [Package option (for xcolor) is not being properly used in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641909/package-option-for-xcolor-is-not-being-properly-used-in-beamer) and to the comment of @Marijin I could run the example using this line `\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass`.

The accepted answer in the link however gives two options. The other one, i.e. adding `\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` before `\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}` does produce the same error    `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color` Yellow3'` for me, therefore it does not work in my case.

Comment: well naturally you need to pass the options you want. Here you want `x11names` so use that not `dvipsnames` in your second version